# Retrieving Facebook friends list through Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, quickblox

I am trying to retrieve a list of a user's Facebook friends by using the code

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"
                             parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
 NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
 NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
 for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
 NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@", friend.name, friend.id);
 }
 }];
```

But whenever I use that code it just returns Found: 0 friends. I'm putting it inside the Viewcontroller to execute after the user logs in through Facebook. I already requested user_friends permissions and I have a friend who is signed up on the app. If it makes any difference the app is also using Quickblox SDK so if there's any way to do it with that that'd be great!

Comment: please go through this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ and use latest Facebook sdk

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph Api v2.0 me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m)

Comment: I already have the latest Facebook SDK installed

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
FBRequest *friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,NSDictionary *result ,NSError *error){

    NSLog(@"Friend data :%@",result);
    NSArray *friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

    NSLog(@"friends :%@",friends);

    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {

        NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@",friend.name,friend.id);

    }     
}];
```

Comment: When I used this I got Friend data: (null) and friends: (null)

Comment: @user3820460,any of your friend should use Facebook app you created,I think not get all of your friends list,which of friends use app,only that list is retrieved

Comment: I had one of my friends login to the app through the simulator and he has an account, but it's obviously not installed on his phone or anything, he just logged in through the simulator.

Comment: @user3820460,then you will get friend list array contain one member,check all permissions user_friends,etc...

Comment: I should only need permission for user_friends right? I already have that.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m?rq=1)

This is by design and has been discussed dozens of times here.

Comment: I requested user_friends permission, and I have a friend who is registered on the app, so he should be showing up according to that answer right?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to asking questions on stackoverflow. I edited it.